# Mapbox GL custom text in cluster circles calculated by custom point data

Tags: text, cluster-computing, customization, mapbox-gl-js

I'm following the standard example for clustering but I'm wanting to know if it's possible to replace the standard 'point_count" text that is placed in the cluster circles.

In my GEOJson data I have a property called "PositiveNegative" for each of my locations/points that equals 1 or 0. eg:
`{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":151,"PositiveNegative":1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-43.5663102,172.5922134]}}`

I would like to work out the total positive vs negative locations within each cluster and place some custom text inside each cluster. eg: "23 Positive / 18 Negative" :see my quick mockup:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
map.addLayer({
                        id: "clusters",
                        type: "circle",
                        source: "posNegPoints",
                        filter: ["has", "point_count"],
                        paint: {
                            "circle-color": [
                                "step",
                                ["get", "point_count"],
                                "#51bbd6",
                                100,
                                "#f1f075",
                                750,
                                "#f28cb1"
                            ],
                            "circle-radius": [
                                "step",
                                ["get", "point_count"],
                                20,
                                100,
                                30,
                                750,
                                40
                            ]
                        }
                    });

map.addLayer({
                        id: "cluster-count",
                        type: "symbol",
                        source: "posNegPoints",
                        filter: ["has", "point_count"],
                        layout: {
                            "text-field": "{point_count_abbreviated}",
                            "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
                            "text-size": 12
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Aggregation by properties is not yet built into the API. But look at this example: https://bl.ocks.org/ryanbaumann/01b2c7fc0ddb7b27f6a72217bd1461ad

Comment: Agreed with @stdob-- it seems that supercluster is the way to go. However the example available at https://bl.ocks.org/ryanbaumann/01b2c7fc0ddb7b27f6a72217bd1461ad is broken: when zooming in to a given level (above 15 if I remember) the visualization is broken. Try to zoom in as much as possible and then do anything else. The whole map is then stuck. Would be nice to have a working example that does clustering up to a certain level and then shows individual points. Currently working on this, but if someone beats me to it, I'll happily try it out :).